# How to solve Column 'Policy_No' does not belong to table?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, buttonclick

I have a simple interface which has a text box, button and a gridview. I want to display the number in the  gridview when click the button. But I get an ArgumentException saying **"Column 'Policy_No' does not belong to table"**. what should I do to solve it. Here I have added the code below.

Button Click Event

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Policy_No"] = txtPolicy.Text.Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    grdPolicy.DataSource = dt;
    grdPolicy.DataBind();
}
```

Page Load code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Policy_No", typeof(string)));
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadCompetitionsNames();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `new DataTable` inside `btnAdd_Click` that doesn't have `column` `Policy_No`

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //dt = new DataTable();   Remove this line
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Policy_No"] = txtPolicy.Text.Trim();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        grdPolicy.DataSource = dt;
        grdPolicy.DataBind();

        Session["PolicyTable"] = dt;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if(Session["PolicyTable"] !=null)
          dt = Session["PolicyTable"] as DataTable;
       else
          dt = new DataTable();

       if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Policy_No"))
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Policy_No", typeof(string)));

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             loadCompetitionsNames();

        }
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the answer. Still i'm not allowed to accept the answer. But i will do for sure.

Comment: How can I add multiple values to the grid one by one?

Comment: What do you mean by `one by one` ?

Comment: To add one row for each button  click. In this code it replaces the prevailing value.

Comment: Then you will need to store the `dt` in session or may be in `cache` to retrieve old values.

Comment: Again I got the same exception

Comment: Also it doesn't allow me to enter this code " as DataTable();". It shows an error

Comment: Sorry remove `()` from `DataTable()`

Comment: OK, its fine. But i get the same exception again

Comment: I made it. Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Add column definition at Button Click Event

```
public DataTable GetGridData()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Policy_No", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Policy_No"] = txtPolicy.Text.Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
} 

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdPolicy.DataSource = GetGridData();
    grdPolicy.DataBind();
}
```

Remove initialization of dt(DataTable) from page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         loadCompetitionsNames();
    }
}
```

You can use session to keep dt data on page postback